# how to increase cupertino time picker range more than 24h flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-cupertino

I tried to increase the range of Cupertino pickers of more than 24h but didn’t get any success
[image]

I am surprised if there is any way to increase the range to more than 24 as only 12 or 24h format is available.
I need Valuable suggestions

Comment: Can you share your code sample?

Comment: well it has simple checks which doesn’t useful at all so I revert changes

Comment: I don't think there's an available solution for this yet. But you might be able to copy the code of the picker and adjust it so it works, since it's all open source

Comment: i prefer to take your answer as i am clueless now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating custom picker with [`CupertinoPicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html).

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: CupertinoPicker(
    itemExtent: 33,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
    children: List.generate(
      34,
      (index) => Text("$index"),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: it helps to set hours but what about minutes?

Comment: You can create another `CupertinoPicker` inside row.

Comment: mean add row in child and add two cupertinoPicker inside it?

Comment: for example, I want my user to start from the current time when the user opens picker e.g current time is 12:08 and when the user clicks on the picker the date is automatically selected.

Comment: like initialDateTime in CupertinoDatePicker